# What do we call the restriction of some function to a certain domain?

Tags: notation, terminology

What do we call the restriction of some function to a certain subset of its domain and range?

Suppose some function $g:\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Q}$ is an extension of a function $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$.

Is there a term for $g$ restricted to $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. It seems like the answer is "yes, the word you used, 'restriction', is the term for the thing you called a 'restriction'."

Comment: It's common to see exactly what you've written: $g$ restricted to $\mathbb N$, but in most cases the restriction on the range is not written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restriction_(mathematics)) implies, I believe "restriction (of a function)" is most commonly used to modify the domain only. Without context suggesting otherwise, I would interpret "$g$ restricted to $\mathbb N$" as meaning a function $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb Q$ with $f(n)=g(n)$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$.

However, there is precedent for using the word "restriction" to refer to modifying the codomain or both. [A part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restriction_(mathematics)#Left-_and_right-restriction) of the same wikipedia page talks about "left-restrictions" and "right-restrictions" for the two sets.

For a text reference, [Topology and Groupoids](http://groupoids.org.uk/topgpds.html) by [Ronald Brown](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/28586/ronnie-brown) explicitly calls modifying both a restriction. In the book's notation, if $f:A\to B$, $A'\subseteq A$, $B'\subseteq B$, and $f(a)\in B'$ for all $a\in A'$ then $f\mid A',B'$ is the restriction of $f$ which maps $A'\to B'$. (Well, the book writes "$fa$" in where I wrote "$f(a)$".)

Comment: I'm interpreting $fa$ to be pretty much interchangeable with $f(a)$ when getting into groups in which composition is the group operation? Rather than a typo.

Comment: @RobertFrost Well, we don't have to talk about it from a group perspective, per se, but yes, it's not a typo - that book just drops parentheses for arguments of functions.